# Restoring deleted email POSTFIX

Tags: centos, dovecot

I have problem with emails for domain. I just deleted domain from webmin, and all emails for domain example.com was deleted.

I want restore these mails.

I use postfix, dovecot and my system is CentOS 6.7.

Is it possible to restore?

Answer (score 1):

Undelete is hard on most linux filesystems. Unless webmin has not actually deleted the emails (check on the commandline! Mail is usually stored in /var/mail/) you are probably out of luck.

Other options for recovery:
Most desktop (=> not phones, tablets) IMAP clients usually have a local cache of all the emails which probably can be used to restore them from the client if you have no backup of the server data.

Comment: Webmin has deleted the emails :( And there is problem becouse, no one used IMAP clients :(